# How do internal websites on corporate networks automatically authenticate the users?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, saml

In a corporate environment when a user logs onto their laptop they can be automatically authenticated for internal websites.

How is this implemented? How does the website and browser know who the user is and authenticate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a myriad of ways, but the canonical method is through a protocol like Kerberos. The process is as follows:

1. Log onto your machine with credentials of some sort, these credentials grant you what's called a ticket-granting-ticket (TGT).
2. You open your browser and go to an internal website `https://internal/page.html`.
3. The website responds with an `HTTP 401` error code and a header `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate`.
4. The browser detects this and calls into the GSS/SSPI services of the OS and says "please give me a ticket to `http/internal` using the `negotiate` package".
5. The GSS/SSPI services see you have a TGT and call to the KDC (Active Directory) and ask for a ticket to `http/internal`.
6. The KDC says "sure" and returns the ticket to the client.
7. The GSS/SSPI service converts the ticket into what's called an `AP-REQ`, wraps it in an `SPNEGO` message and returns it to the browser.
8. The browser encodes it into base64, sticks it in an `Authorization: Negotiate {base64}` header and retries the request to the site.
9. The site receives the header, detects it's Negotiate, so it passes it off the it's own GSS/SSPI services.
10. Those services decode the message, extract the AP-REQ, decrypt it, and verify it's something it understands.
11. An identity is extracted from the ticket and presented to the web application internals.

All the end-user did is (1) and (2). The client machine did the rest.

Then higher-level protocols like SAML et al can rely on the flow above to authenticate you to an IdP, which can then fire tokens off to whatever relying parties you might have.

Answer (score -1):

There are couple of ways as mentioned. One is through the Windows Integrated Authentication and any Single Sign On methods like the OKTA, Microsoft ADFS.

Its a pretty good experience from a user perspective as we don't need to remember so many credentials

Comment: This is not a good answer.  It lacks detail.  See Steve's answer above for how to write a good answer on SO.